# INSERT INTO from SQL Table with specified order

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to insert data from one SQL database table into another.  It needs to be inserted in a specified order as I am planning on extracting the data in the table to a csv file to create a catalogue.  I have over 50000 items in my main table and want to extract about 500 into the new table.

I have created a form to enter the reference number (ref) which creates an array of reference numbers.

```
  <form action="list.php" method="post">
          <p>List Number <input name="list_no" type="text"></p>
      <table align="center" width="50%">
    <tr>
        <td><input name="item[]" type="text" style="width: 80px"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input name="item[]" type="text" style="width: 80px"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input name="item[]" type="text" style="width: 80px"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input name="item[]" type="text" style="width: 80px"></td>
        <td></td>
        <td><input name="item[]" type="text" style="width: 80px"></td>
    </tr>
      </table>
  <p>Step 4: Create List.<input name="Submit1" type="submit" value="Create List" /></p>
```

On list.php I have created the code to create a new table in my database with the name list... depending on the number entered on the form.  My data from the table in assigned to the array

```
$item=$_POST['item'];
```

I know the data in $item is in the order I entered it to the form as I have used  $item_list = implode(",", $item); and echo $item_list to check the order of the entered data, and to get the data separated by a comma.

My list.php page then uses the code

```
$insert="INSERT INTO list$list_no (ref, description, price_s) 
         SELECT ref, description, price_s 
         FROM stock 
        WHERE ref IN ($item_list)";
```

`mysql_query($insert) or die(mysql_error());`

to enter the items into the new table.  It enters all items that have been requested, however appears to enter them in order of ref, rather than order of the way I entered them onto the original form.

Any ideas on how to rectify this problem?

Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like ref is an index. can you not just add an ORDER BY clause to your SELECT query for writing to csv?

Comment: What is your primary key? Can you post your SQL schema?

Comment: Inserting with a specific order does not make any sense. Rows in a table are **not** sorted.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: that should be an answer...

Answer (score 0):

Inserting with a specific order does not make any sense.

Rows in a table are **not** sorted.

You have to sort them during retrieveal (from the "list" table) using an `ORDER BY`

MySQL will re-order the rows during inserting anyway due to it's clustered index on the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

> It needs to be inserted in a specified order

It is not.

> as I am planning on extracting the data in the table to a csv file to create a catalogue.

You are welcome to use ORDER BY for this operation.

> I have over 50000 items in my main table and want to extract about 500 into the new table.

You don't want it again. Having 2 tables with the same date makes no sense.
Why can't you generate your CSV from the original table already?

Answer (score -1):

You need to `ORDER BY` by the `ref` field in the SELECT query, `FIND_IN_SET` will preserve the order:

```
$insert = sprintf("INSERT INTO list%s (ref, description, price_s) 
                   SELECT ref, description, price_s 
                   FROM stock 
                   WHERE ref IN ('%s')
                   ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(ref, '%s')", $list_no, $item_list, $item_list);
```

EDIT: You really should change your database design. This is not a good approach.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply.  What does %s represent?  I have just run the query you suggested, and it adds the first item form the form into the new table, but does not add anything else.  
How do you suggest the database should be designed?  Thansk

Comment: %s - represents a string. so the first %s will be replaced with $list_no. Please see [sprintf](http://fr2.php.net/sprintf)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.  on the article you posted it said that sprintf works the same as printf, so I replaced sprintf with printf and recieved this error: "INSERT INTO list102 (ref, description, price_s) SELECT ref, description, price_s FROM stock WHERE ref IN ('45154,64608,26830,66118,65386') ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(ref, '45154,64608,26830,66118,65386')You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '197' at line 1". I;m also still only inserting the first item into the table.